# How to add link to another html in ghost post on azure

Tags: azure, ghost

I created a ghost blog on the Azure. In one of my posts I want to create a link for another webpage that I is not a post/blog but an independent page that I have created separately and want to upload there in my ghost directory structure. I have tried following options but none has worked:

- Placed that page.html in wwwroot directory and provided the url "http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/page.html"
- Placed it in wwwroot/content directory and provided the url "http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/content/page.html"

Any idea how can this problem be resolved. Many thanks.

Habib

Answer (score 1):

You have to place `page.html` file in the theme folder.

```
root_dir/content/theme/<your_theme_folder>/page.html
```

Restart Ghost using `ghost restart`.

The page can be now accessed at:

```
http://domain.tld/page.html
```